# == and %in% differ based on character encoding?

Tags: r, character-encoding

I'm having a hard time understanding why `==` and `%in%` would produce different results when applied to character vectors that depend, it seems, only on vectors' encoding. An example:

```
a <- 'Köln'
Encoding(a) <- 'unknown'
Encoding(a)
# [1] "unknown"

b <- a
Encoding(b) <- 'UTF-8'

a == b
# [1] TRUE
a %in% b
# [1] FALSE
```

**Update**:

It appears the result is also platform-dependent. The two statements return:

- `TRUE` and `FALSE` on R 3.3.0 on OS X 10.11.5
- `FALSE` and `FALSE` on R 3.3.0 on Windows 10 (64 bit)
- `TRUE` and `TRUE` on R 3.2.3 on CentOS 7

I'm starting to think this is a bug.

Comment: `a %in% c(a,b)` is true `?Encoding` -- `match, pmatch, charmatch, duplicated and unique all match in UTF-8 if any of the elements are marked as UTF-8.`

Comment: And the documentation for `==` says that characters are all converted to UTF-8 before comparison...I'd be curious why the different behavior though.

Comment: @rawr Well yeah, but `a` is in `c(a)` so it's also in `c(a,b)`. But why isn't `b` in `c(a)`? `%in%` doesn't check for the variable name being identical, only values and I don't understand why the values aren't identical given that `==` returns `TRUE`.

Comment: The docs for `match` say "Character strings will be compared as byte sequences if any input is marked as "bytes"". Is `unknown` a byte sequence?

Comment: `unknown` is not `bytes`, as discussed in `?Encoding`. I would have thought that the fact that `==` _actually alters the encoding_ before doing the comparison would have made things clearer...?

Comment: @joran Maybe I'm dense. `==` changing the encoding to UTF-8 before comparison explains why `==` returns `TRUE`. But what do `%in%`/`match` use to determine whether a match has been found other than `==`?

Comment: Ah. Well, `match` descends pretty much immediately to internal C code. So their implementations are sort of orthogonal.

Comment: Dude, WTF... On my Cygwin 3.1.3 installation I get `TRUE` for both tests, but on my RStudio 3.2.1 installation I get `FALSE` for both tests. And you (the OP) seem to get a mixture. Nothing makes sense... Nothing makes sense...

Comment: `TRUE` and `FALSE` on R 3.3.0 on OS X 10.11.5.
`FALSE` and `FALSE` on R 3.3.0 on Windows 10 (64 bit).

Comment: `TRUE` and `TRUE` on R 3.2.3 on CentOS 7

Comment: I get TRUE TRUE using R 3.3.0 patched (2016-06-09 r70753) on openSUSE 13.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed a bug, and it was [fixed in 3.3.1](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=16885).

The behavior is actually a bit weirder than your example indicates, in that you only get `FALSE` when you have one element on the left-hand side of `%in%`:

```
> a %in% b
[1] FALSE
> c(a, a) %in% b
[1] TRUE TRUE
```

As implied by the comments, `%in%` just calls `match`, so the problem can be seen there too:

```
> match(a, b)
[1] NA
> match(c(a, a), b)
[1] 1 1
```

The important arguments to `%in%` and `match` are `x` and `table`, where either function searches for `x` in `table`. Under the hood, R does this in the `match5` function defined in `unique.c`. In the case where you have more than one `x`, `match5` will create a hash table from `table` to enable fast lookups. If you dig through the code, you'll see that the comparison is done in a function called `sequal`, which returns `Seql(STRING_ELT(x, i), STRING_ELT(y, j))` (well, it's actually a bit more complex than this*). Then if you go look at `Seql` in `memory.c`, you'll find:

```
int result = !strcmp(translateCharUTF8(a), translateCharUTF8(b));
```

Which, as you can see, converts the strings to UTF-8.

However, if `x` only has one element, it's silly to go through the trouble of creating a hash table, since we can just scan through `table` once to see if `x` is there. In 3.3.0, the code to check for equality between `x` and each element of `table` didn't use `Seql` and didn't convert the string to UTF-8. But starting in 3.3.1, `Seql` is used, so the behavior is fixed.

* A little aside on string equality: R will actually cache strings so that it doesn't have to store a bunch of copies. So if two strings are at the same location, they're equal and there's no need to check further!

```
> .Internal(inspect("Köln"))
@10321b758 16 STRSXP g0c1 [NAM(2)] (len=1, tl=0)
  @106831eb8 09 CHARSXP g1c1 [MARK,gp=0x28,ATT] [UTF8] [cached] "Köln"
> .Internal(inspect(b))
@106831cd8 16 STRSXP g1c1 [MARK,NAM(2)] (len=1, tl=0)
  @106831eb8 09 CHARSXP g1c1 [MARK,gp=0x28,ATT] [UTF8] [cached] "Köln"
```